# Retrieve table name from SQL Create statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have code that executes a sql create table statement from outside my code, like so:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(aConnectionString);
connection.Open();
string createTable = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("CreateTable.sql");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTable, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is it possible to determine the name of the newly created table WITHOUT parsing it directly from the sql statement string?

Comment: The most reliable way would indeed be parse the script. Sure, you could try and query the system tables, but in a concurrent system, that may very well not give you the correct results.

Comment: It would really help us if you explained what you are trying to accomplish instead of just saying what you are doing. See the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution I think ... But you can get the last table created / changed in your database with this query.

```
select name,type,type_desc, create_date, modify_date from sys.objects
where  convert(varchar,modify_date,101)  =  convert(varchar,getdate(),101) AND type = 'U'
order by modify_date desc
```

Comment: There is no indication from the question that the table was created the same day the name is to be determined. Or, even if it was, that it was the last such table.